# How to get the Table HTML format into function?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

How to return the value with The table HTML format?

the output is only getting the table codes but not the data from the google sheets.

My function

```
    //Table Data
function getData() {
  const headerColumns = 5;  // In your case, the number of header columns is 5.
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1BKeSPqcy5_BjW7mbUpXhUhSVuuBwqeY5iHkOAec').getSheetByName("TODAY");
  const values = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), headerColumns).getDisplayValues();
  console.log(values)
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('table').getContent();
}
```

table.html

```
<div class="form-row">
<table class="table" id="table">
  <? var [header, ...data] = getData(); ?>
  <thead class="thead-dark"><tr>
  <? for (var j = 0; j < header.length; j++) { ?>
    <th><?= header[j] ?></th>
  <? } ?>
  </tr></thead>

  <? for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { ?>
  <tr class="in_out">
    <? for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) { ?>
    <td><?= data[i][j] ?></td>
    <? } ?>
  </tr>
  <? } ?>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: I cannot understand about `the output is only getting the table codes but not the data from the google sheets.`. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue and goal?

Comment: @Tanaike I want to load the table when clicking on the button on Google web app. but I'm not getting it right with ID where my table is getting jumbled, You can have look at my google sheet>tools>script editor>testing TimeTracker to get a better understanding. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BKeSPqcy5_BjW7mbUpXhUhSVuuBweMsFqeY5iHkOAec/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I couldn't still understand about your question. By the way, also I couldn't see your sample Spreadsheet. I apologize for this.

Comment: @Tanaike This is employees Timetracker, I want to display data which is gathered from google sheet when the button is clicked. I'm having some trouble to configure the button ID and Table into function. I'm adding some screenshot for your better understanding 
Before Button is clicked https://i.imgur.com/FAvmopS.jpg
After button is clicked https://i.imgur.com/CFFyRB1.jpg

Comment: This is the frontend link https://script.google.com/a/macros/autodirect.lk/s/AKfycbzVFbUENi2rhjcZi7OXibQo9JibmjxPBveDAmMtgwCBVIu-GoE/exec

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot understand your provided sample images from your script. So I cannot still think of the solution. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. When I could correctly understand about your question, I would like to think of the solution. I apologize that I cannot resolve your issue soon.

Comment: What I assume is, the function is only returning the data but not the HTML format.

Comment: It seems the HTML service `HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile` doesn't work this way. In fact it takes an existing html file and returns an html object that can be used somehow within GAS environment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html#code.gs I don't know if there is a function to get a proper html table from a spreadsheet. I'd try just to write the html directly <table><tr><td>...</td></tr>... etc.

Comment: Can you either provide sheet access or explain more in detial what you are doing? Are you deploying a WebApp? Can you show the `doGet()` and/or other relevant funcitons to make your code run?

Comment: @ziganotschka I've given access for you.

Comment: @ziganotschka I want to load the employee time log data when the button SHOW TABLE is clicked with newly updated data in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [Apps Script scriptlets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#scriptlets) only work in a template that is evaluated within the `doGet()` function

In your case, you are evaluating `TimeTracker.html` within `doGet()`, but your table with the scriptlets is located within the `table.html` file that is included in the former.

**Solution:**

Insert

```
<table class="table" id="table">
  <? var [header, ...data] = getData(); ?>
  <thead class="thead-dark"><tr>
  <? for (var j = 0; j < header.length; j++) { ?>
    <th><?= header[j] ?></th>
  <? } ?>
  </tr></thead>

  <? for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { ?>
  <tr class="in_out">
    <? for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) { ?>
    <td><?= data[i][j] ?></td>
    <? } ?>
  </tr>
  <? } ?>
</table>
```

directly into the `<body>` of the `TimeTracker.html` file.

Indeed, you can insert the whole content of `table.html` into `TimeTracker.html` and get rid of `<?!= include("table"); ?>`.

**UPDATE**

Sample how to update paste your data into an HTML table on google.script.run serverside:

```
function getData() {
  Logger.log("get data called");
  const headerColumns = 5;  // In your case, the number of header columns is 5.
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX').getSheetByName("TODAY");
  const values = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), headerColumns).getDisplayValues();
  console.log(values);
  var table = "";
  for(var i = 0; i < values.length; i++){
    table += "<tr>";
    for(var j = 0; j < values[0].length; j++){
      table += "<td>";
      table += values[i][j];
      table += "</td>";
    }
    table += "</tr>";
  }
  return table;
}
```

The success handler could look like:

```
  function onSuccess(myString){
  console.log("string: " + myString);
  document.getElementById("table").innerHTML=myString;
  }
```

Mind that currently `getData()` is getting all data from the sheet. You still need to implement a filtering functionality to return only the data for a certain employee (if this is your purpose).

Comment: @ziganotshka I've done that part as you said, can you please help me with one more problem? I'm having some issue with loading the table when I click on the SHOW ME button. It's giving me the raw data without the HTML content in it, where did I go wrong?

Comment: The formatted data is evaluated only once, when the page is loaded. If you want to update your table on button click (e.g. after selecting a user) - you need to create each time a new html table, and this you can do best server side within the Apps Script `getData()` function - dynamically with `for` loops.